# Try to create a scrollView with labels

Tags: swift, swift3, scrollview

I'm a little new in swift. I'm trying to make a simple scrollview with a label that changes its value, but I can not get it to work properly.

This is my code:

```
class ConsejosController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate {

var asunto = ["value1", "value2"]

@IBOutlet weak var lbl_asunto: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet weak var pageControl: UIPageControl!


var contentWidth: CGFloat = 0.0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        scrollView.delegate = self

        for etiqueta in 0...1{

            contentWidth += view.frame.width

            lbl_asunto.text = asunto[etiqueta]

        }

        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: contentWidth, height: view.frame.height)


    }

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        pageControl.currentPage = Int(scrollView.contentOffset.x / CGFloat(375) )
    }

}
```

This don't work properly. Directly show "value2" and don't scroll

Any advice?

Comment: It is only taking last value which is `value2` with your for loop

Comment: But if I remove the loop, how do I first show the 'value1' and then the 'value2' when scrolling? Sorry, I'm very new with swift

Comment: You don't need to remove it but with every loop you need to correctly set your label and I suggest add your label programmatically since you are using for loop and give position accordingly

Comment: Thanks Dharmesh Khan. That was the trick! I have done the label programmatically and it works better. But not well at all. I put you in an answer as I have done. But I have a small mistake. Show the two labels in the same page.

Answer (score 0):

I made the for cycle in this way:

```
for etiqueta in 0...1{

            contentWidth += view.frame.width

            let label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 21))
            label.center = CGPoint(x: 160, y: 285)
            label.textAlignment = .center
            label.text = asunto[etiqueta]
            self.scrollView.addSubview(label)

        }
```

Now scrolling well, but show two labels 'value1' and 'value2' in the same page one over another, and the second page empty.